# I don't know how to prove some class of models is whether an elementary class or an elementary class in the wider sense. How can I prove what it is?

Tags: logic, model-theory

First some definitions: For a set Σ of L-sentences, Mod(Σ) denotes the class of all models that satisfy Σ. For a class M of models, we say it is EC if M=Mod(σ) for some sentence σ and ECΔ if M=Mod(Σ).

Problem. Let T be a theory having arbitrary large finite models. (For example, T can be axioms for groups, or fields, or linear orderings.) Let Kinf={M : M⊨T, Card(|M|) is infinite.} and Kfin={M : M⊨T, Card(|M|) is finite}.

Question.

(a) Kinf is ECΔ

(b) Kfin is not ECΔ

(c) Kinf is not EC

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? Question-only problems are very likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just give hints, the rest is up to you :

a) Consider the theory $$T_{inf} := T \cup \{\exists x_1 \exists x_2 \dots \exists x_n \bigwedge_{1\leqslant i < j \leqslant n} x_i \neq x_j \ \big| \ n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$
The models of $T_{inf}$ are precisely the infinite models of $T$.

b) assume for contradiction that Kfin is ECΔ. Now consider an ultraproduct, say $U$, of arbitrarily large finite models of $T$ : $U$ is an infinite model of $T$. Since an  ECΔ class is closed under ultraproducts, $U$ is also in Kfin, a contradiction.

c) assume for contradiction that Kinf is EC, ie there is a sentence $\sigma$ such that Kinf $ = \operatorname{Mod}(\sigma)$. Then the models in Kfin are precisely the models of $T \cup \{\neg \sigma\}$ : hence Kfin is ECΔ, a contradiction to point b).